# What version of the Mobile SDK is an existing iOS app running?

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

Does anyone know of a good way to figure out which version of the Salesforce iOS Mobile SDK an existing iOS app is running? I believe it was generated using the `forceios` npm package, but that npm installation is long since gone.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2):

There is a file called `SalesforceSDKConstants.h` in the SalesforceSDKCore directory.

You can:
`#import "SalesforceSDKConstants.h"` and then later `NSLog(@"%@",SALESFORCE_SDK_VERSION);` . I was on 2.0.1, so this is valid for that version at least.